# Design rearranging/sorting of ListView

Tags: android, list, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` which displays some customized items.
The requirement is to give user the facility to change position of the list items up & down.
For rearranging I'm planning to use: [drag-sort-listview](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobeta.android.demodslv)

#### Scenario:

There will be two *listviews*:

1. The original list displayed in beginning.
2. List with rearrange handlers on the right [like this](https://lh4.ggpht.com/E-81q9dqPEm9imAIjvHxk4geEGx7lC-ddjuOr4pIzlUrxhreI883FVPIs2J7nX1Uxes=h900)

When the app starts, the first list is displayed, but when the user clicks rearrange button, the second list with handlers is displayed.
The transition between the two list should be in such a way that the position is maintained & the same list is being displayed.

#### Issue:

What is the best approach to design this case.
Should I make two listviews? If yes, then how to pass data between the two with maintaining transition?
Or, show/hide the handlers within one list?